# How can I detect that the (X) close button of a jQuery UI Dialog was clicked, separately from the dialogclose/dialogbeforeclose events?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I'd like to be able to detect the (x) close button of a jQuery UI Dialogue being clicked, but I don't want to use the `dialogclose` / `dialogbeforeclose` events (since I believe these will fire regardless of how the dialog was closed).

I tried `$(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").live("click")`, but that doesn't seem to work.

How can I do this?

Sample code: (the debugger doesn't fire up when the dialogue is closed).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog();

    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").live("click", function() { 
        debugger; // ** clicking the close button doesn't get to here.**
        });
  });
  </script>
</head>

<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">I'm in a dialog</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use the `create` event to bind your functionality

Answer (score 30, accepted):

you could do exactly what **JAAulde** suggested, or avoiding tracking binding and use the `create` event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        create: function() {
            $(this).closest('div.ui-dialog')
                   .find('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close')
                   .click(function(e) {
                       alert('hi');
                       e.preventDefault();
                   });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Ah, I knew there had to be a `create`-like method/event, but I didn't bother looking it up. +1 and you should get accepted answer over mine!

Comment: Just curious, do you have any idea why `$(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").live("click")` doesn't fire? It does fire if changed the event to like `mouseover`

Comment: I am not entirely sure about this but `live` binds at DOM root, in the case of `click` it does not bubble up since the widget already triggers execution on this element and the chain is not continued, more involved debugging could uncover the reason

Comment: @therefromhere I suspect the click handler bound by UI (for closing the dialog) stops propagation of the click event thereby keeping the live-bound handler from triggering. I'd have to read the source to be sure, though.

Comment: This no longer works in jquery ui 1.9+. Replace the find with: `.find('button.ui-dialog-titlebar-close')`

Comment: Why not do `find('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close')` then it works regardless of version.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question, and the OP said he didn't want to use beforeClose, but the reason was because it always fires, even for things other than the X. However, I noticed that the techniques here don't allow me to prevent a dialog from closing (I want a confirm window to open if there are unsaved changes). If we Ithe techniques here, use beforeClose, we can achieve the desired result, but make it cancellable. I used:

```
beforeClose: function (e, ui) {
    if ($(e.currentTarget).hasClass('ui-dialog-titlebar-close') && whateverMyConditionIs)
        e.preventDefault();
}
```

Thought it might help someone else!

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for! This is the simplest way to check if a user clicked on the X and ask for a confirmation before closing it, while still allowing the dialog to be closed instantly by another function.

Comment: Great answer. The beforeClose is always fired though, so the filter for class of clicked item is essential in this solution. +1. However, any close even will fire this beforeClose event, so there needs to be provisions for a 'Close' button if offered and this close button will NOT have a close event fired, so the dialog will need to be closed in code for the button, but not for the 'X' of the dialog.

Comment: This worked for me.  I couldn't figure out how to have multiple title bar buttons so I crammed them all in to the close button with "$(".myDialog").parent().find("button.ui-dialog-titlebar-close").html(--my own buttons in here--");.  That way I can capture each button click separately --including the close button which I added using font awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Really good question

It's working if You use only the click

```
 $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").click( function() { 
        debugger;
        });
```

But i'm sure there's a reason for the live ?

I'll continue looking

And why you don't want to use this ?

```
$('.selector').bind('dialogclose', function(event, ui) {
   debugger;
});
```

Comment: this was perfect for what I wanted - the bind approach. Thanks!

Comment: I must agree with GregM - why not a simple 'bind' of all the answers on this page this was the only one that worked for me.  It may have had something to do with the fact that my dialogue was being created dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to do this via `.live` etc as you'll end up binding to the X of every dialog you create. You want to bind to a specific dialog's X for a specific purpose, so...

**Note**
Before you read on, note that this works perfectly but is overly complex. **Kris Ivanov** has posted a more correct, more concise, more appropriate answer.
**End Note**

In the dialog's open method, check to see if you've already bound the click to the 'X'. If not, flag that you have and then find your instance's 'X' and bind it:

```
$( function()
{
    $( '#dialog' ).dialog( {
        open: function() //runs every time this dialog is opened
        {
            var $dialog = $( this );

            if( ! $dialog.data( 'titleCloseBound' ) )
            {
                $dialog
                    .data( 'titleCloseBound', true ) //flag as already bound
                    .closest( 'div.ui-dialog' ) //traverse up to the outer dialog wrapper
                        .find( 'a.ui-dialog-titlebar-close' ) //search within it for the X
                            .bind( 'click', function( e ) //bind it
                            {
                                alert( 'hi' );
                                e.preventDefault();
                            } );
            }
        }
    } );
} );
```

You need the check for whether it has been bound because `open` runs every time the dialog opens, so multiple opens would rebind the same functionality over and over without it.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/XM2FH/

Comment: not very efficient to keep track of binding, just use `create` event instead of `open`

Comment: @KrisIvanov lol, yeah, see my comment to your answer and my added note to mine.

Comment: yep, did not see it sry, did not downgrade, still useful information